# $('form').submit(); doesnt seem to fire within a function

Tags: jquery

I am working on a page locally and seem to have an issue with jQuery and `submit()`. I have no other jQuery on the page apart from what is below.

I have 3 menus each with id's of `sel1`, `sel2` and `sel3`. If I add `alert('hereX');` as in the following code the alert box fires on all three references but the form does not submit.

```
$('#sel1').on('change keyup', function () {
    alert('here1');
    $('#f').append("<input type='hidden' name='act1' value=-1 />");
    alert('here2');
    $('#f').submit();
    alert('here3');
    return true;
});
```

My form is as:

```
<form method="post" name="f" action="#1" id="f">
```

My submit button is set as:

```
<input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" onclick="return confirm('You have Javascript enabled')">
```

Does anyone have any pointers as to where the issue might be. The jQuery seems to be getting loaded as the alerts fire but it seems to be the submit thats not submitting the form. I have tried in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

The Javascript code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#sel1').on('change keyup', function () {
            $('#f').append("<input type='hidden' name='act1' value=-1 />");
            $('#f').submit();
            return true;
        });

        $('#sel2').on('change keyup', function () {
            $('#f').append("<input type='hidden' name='act1' value=-2 />");
            $('#f').submit();
            return true;
        });

        $('#sel3').on('change keyup', function () {
            $('#f').append("<input type='hidden' name='act1' value=-3 />");
            $('#f').submit();
            return true;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is a simplified version of the menus, the page uses quite a few lines of PHP and the select dropdowns are loaded dynamically relative to the value sent by act1 in the jquery

```
<select name="f[type]" style="width: 180px;" id="sel1"
<option value="car">Car</option>
<option value="boat">Boat</option>
</select>

<select name="f[color]" style="width: 180px;" id="sel2"
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>

<select name="f[size]" style="width: 180px;" id="sel3"
<option value="5">5</option
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you have a `submit()` event handler on the form? Currently its action is set to `#1`, so it will do nothing unless you handle the submit event yourself. Also note that you could quite simply DRY that code up with a single event handler for all the `selX` elements.

Comment: Sorry yes I do, I have a Submit button with the type as "Submit" and name as "update"

Comment: What exactly are you expecting this form to *do* when you submit it?  Where do you tell the form to do that thing?

Comment: @MikeB Could you please edit your question to include that submit event handler code. A more complete HTML sample would help too as I can show you how to use the DRY principles I mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: OK, the submit button code has been added to the original post

Comment: Having a submit button doesn't mean it will post. The form action is still wrong. `..action="#1"` will not do a lot. Unless you have a JS handler that checks that `window.location.hash` is changed and does an AJAX request or something.

Comment: David, The user selects an option from the menu with id sel1 and then the form submits to itself where the value of the selected menu is received along with the value of the hidden field act1, depending on the act1 being set the menu for sel2 then loads the values relating to the selection from sel1 menu, the same then happens for sel3 menu. All that side works if the submit button is used to submit the form but I am trying to get the form to auto submit on menu selection.

Comment: The Submit button works and sends the form to itself but should I understand that $('#f').submit(); in the jquery does not work the same way without using the button, using the button sends the form to itself and passes the values on so after the three menu values are selected the full form information is then displayed or in my case used for a calculation.

Comment: I would be interested into DRYing up the code Rory, I know I can get the same result using less jquery but my first intention was to get the code to work. Not sure if any pointers can be offered here or if I should make an attempt and post another question if I have any issue.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly *should* this form do when it's submitted?  Look at the action attribute:

```
<form method="post" name="f" action="#1" id="f">
```

What is `#1` supposed to be?  It's not a server-side URL so the form isn't going to actually post anything to a server resource.  It's going to basically do nothing.

> I have no other jQuery on the page apart from what is below.

Then there's no `submit` event handler for this form, other than the `#1` action which doesn't do anything.  By default the form doesn't know what you want it to do, it needs to be told.  Either with a valid `action` or with an in-code `submit` event handler.

Something like this:

```
<form method="post" name="f" action="someUrl.php" id="f">
```

Or this:

```
$('#f').submit(function () {
    // do something here
});
```

Comment: OK, I changed the action to the name of the page from #1 to calc.php which is the page name and it still doesn't submit!

Comment: @MikeB: I'm not able to replicate the behavior you're describing: https://jsfiddle.net/c98x8sg6/

Answer (score 0):

Hey because the form action is #1, it is not working.
you have to change the form action or make a another submit event handler for the form.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the issue was a second submit button set dynamically to the page with the same name as one of the other buttons that get published at different stages, once that was removed the form worked so the duplicate naming of the button was causing a conflict.

Sorry I didn't discover this before, there is an quite an amount of php code used throughout the page and I must have got myself tied up in the issue rather than paying a bit more on what was going on elsewhere.

Just a point on the form action being set to #1, after I found what the issue was the form actually works having the action set to #1 or set to its actual file name so that doesn't seem to make a difference

Thanks for taking the time on all the answers.